# Get all possible combinations on a large dataset in R

Tags: r, combinations

I am having a large dataset having more than 10 million records and 20 variables. I need to get every possible combination for 11 variables out of these 20 variables and for each combination the frequency also should be displayed.

I have tried count() in plyr package and table() function. But both of them are unable to get all possible combinations, since the number of combinations are very high (greater than 2^32 combinations) and also the size is huge.

Assume following dataset having 5 variables and 6 observations - 
[image: original dataset]

And I want all possible combinations of first three variables where frequencies are greater than 0.

[image: combinations dataset]
Is there any other function to achieve this? I am just interested in combinations whose frequency is non-zero.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide a little more detail on what you mean by *"every possible combination"*. Can you give a sample dataset of (say) 10 rows of 5 variables where you need every combination of 3 of those variables? (And provide what those combinations should look like.)

Comment: Do you want all 20-choose-11 combinations of column names? It's not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I have an idea of what you require. If you are saying you want the count by N categories of rows in your table, you can do so with the `data.table` package. It will give you the count of all combinations that exist in the table. Simply list the required categories in the `by` arguement

```
DT<-data.table(val=rnorm(1e7),cat1=sample.int(10,1e7,replace = T),cat2=sample.int(10,1e7,replace = T),cat3=sample.int(10,1e7,replace = T))
DT_count<-DT[, .N, by=.(cat1,cat2,cat3)]
```